# loadScript() returns false error

Tags: ethereumjs

I am using geth and writing a js script and I try to load it using `loadScript` command, but when I run this command, I get false :

```
 loadScript("C:\Users\Sandi\Desktop\Solidity\sol_js.js")
```

> false

I am not able to load the script. How i should do to load it in order to get true message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please note that you are using a **wrong path**, even if you are on Windows change the \ to /
so load the script using :  `loadScript("C:/Users/Sandi/Desktop/Solidity/sol_js.js")`