# Loading Script Geth puppeth

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, ethereumjs, cli

I failed to load a script into a private blockchain setup using puppeth. I have used puppeth to configure a private blockchain (PoA) with a few sealers on different vms. Could someone help?

I now need to load a script. I tried using:

```
geth --preload "/path/to/hello.js"
```

with the error: `Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another process`
since the vm has the sealer nodes running in a docker. The proof is here after running `ps aux`:    geth --networkid <...>--cache <>--port <...>--maxpeers <....>--ethstats <...> --bootnodes ....

I tried loading the script directly through the console by doing this:

```
docker exec -it <container ID> geth  attach ipc:/root/.ethereum/geth.ipc
```

and in the console type:
`loadScript('hello.js')`   where hello.js is in the directory where I typed the geth attach command above. Also tried `loadScript('path to hello')`

All of the following links state that the path to the javascript is incorrect
but I ensured that the file path is where it should or is where I ran geth attach. My goal is to have script running even if I need to stop the docker container and restart geth. But the issue is that I cannot pass the --preload argument because I am using puppeth, I think :)

1. [How can access to a external file using loadScript?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21500/how-can-access-to-a-external-file-using-loadscript)
2. [loadScript() returns false error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9645/loadscript-returns-false-error)